# Browse cube - Change User: The following system error occurred: The user name or password is incorrect

Tags: security, permissions, ssas, business-intelligence, olap-cube

I'm trying to browse SSAS cube using different user and I get "the user name or password is incorrect".
I gave the user Admin rights on the cube, admin rights on the SSAS server and these were not helped.
the only users who can browse the cube are domain admins. 
By the way, browsing the cube directly without changing the user works well.
What is the problem? what should I change?
[image: The ERROR]

Answer (score 1):

You are logged into a laptop or server as DOMAIN\user1 then you try to switch to DOMAIN\user2. Make sure user1 is an SSAS administrator. Impersonating other users requires admin permissions. But user2 does not need admin permissions.

If you are running SSMS on the server itself and user1 permissions as an SSAS admin are granted through the local Windows Administrators group make sure to do Run As Administrator when you launch SSMS.

Comment: is correct, but what if user1 is an administrator and still not able to impersonate user2 but can impersonate user 3. Is this related to Windows Authorization Group in Active Directory?

Comment: @StavrosKoureas good question. I'm not familiar with that. Do you have a link?